# jQuery: prevent animation and timeout queuing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeout, delay, timing

I have probably a simple problem to solve but I don't know what's the right approach on that.

I have a `div.notification` bar on top of my website that is hidden by default. The bar does get an additional class of either `success` or `warning` that sets it to `display:block;` if needed.

So, there are two cases. Either an output message is rendered directly to the `.notification` bar on page-load (and it gets a class of `success` or `warning` right with it) OR the `.notifcation` bar is sliding down from top and is fed with json data.

Any way, the notification bar should always be visible for 10 seconds and than slide back up.

Therefore I wrote two functions that handle this bar.

```
var timing = 10000;
function notificationOutput(type, message) {
    var note = $('.notification');
    note.hide();
    note.find('.message').html(message);
    note.stop(true,true).slideDown().delay(timing).slideUp();
}

function notificationSlideUp(slideUp) {
    var note = $('.notification');

    if ( slideUp ) note.delay(timing).slideUp();
        else note.stop(true,true).slideUp();
}
```

So the `notificationOutput()` function is triggered from various other functions that return json data and render that into the box.

And the `notificationSlideUp()` function is right now called on every page load because in my header I have this …

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        notificationSlideUp(true);
    });
</script>
```

And there is a reason for that! Remember the case where the `.notification` is directly set to visible on page-load … e.g. when a user logs-in on my platform the `.notification` bar is immediately visibile and says "Welcome Username, you've successfully logged in".

I call the `notifictaionSlideUp()` function in my header to make sure the currently visible `.notification` bar will slideUp() again after 10 seconds.

**And here occurs the problem …** 
Somehow this causes the entire notifcation timing and sliding up and down to be "confused". So there must happen some queuing of the slide-functions and or of the delay() function, because without the `note.stop(true,true)` in the `notificationOutput()` function the notification wouldn't slideDown() immediately if it's triggered within the first 10 seconds after the page load. That is because the `notificationSlideUp()` function has already triggered the slideUp() and the delay() of the object.

And the same happens to the delay. If a `.notification` is put out within the first 10 seconds the delay timing isn't right because the delay counter already started on page-load.

Any idea how to solve that so that it always works?

**Update:**

```
var notificationTimer;

function notificationOutput(type, message) {
    var note = $('.notification');
    note.hide();
    note.find('.message').html(message);

    note.stop(true,true).slideDown();

    clearTimeout(notificationTimer);
    notificationTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        note.stop(true,true).slideUp();
    }, 10000);

}

function notificationSlideUp(slideUp) {
    var note = $('.notification');

    if ( slideUp ) {
        clearTimeout(notificationTimer);
        notificationTimer = setTimeout(function() {
            note.stop(true,true).slideUp();
        }, 10000);
    } else {
        note.stop(true,true).slideUp();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, jQuery's `delay()` function doesn't offer any method for canceling a delay the way `setTimeout()` does with `clearTimeout()`. I'd suggest replacing your `delay()`s with named `setTimeout()`s, and writing a condition to `clearTimeout()` for cases in which you need to cancel/trigger a queued animation right away.

Comment: I updated my question with my two functions and `setTimeout`… Is this the right way in using it. Is my codesample correct? It seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/delay/

> The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery
>   effects. **Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to
>   cancel the delay—.delay()** is not a replacement for JavaScript's native
>   setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use
>   cases.

But you can use the following 'hint' - replace delay with some animation which does not change anything. For example with `.animate({opacity:1},timing)`

Comment: Thank you, I updated my question with my two functions and the set- and clearTimeout methods. It seems to be working, but is this the right way of doing it?

Comment: @Matt Did you even try my suggestion? it is just replacement of a couple of words, not a setTimeout function. I prefer elegant and nice solutions.

Comment: I love the solution, really nice trick btw. However in my case it's way more effective now to use setTimeout, so I can clear it from all other functions if I need to!